# Is there an Excel VBA equivalent to XPathNavigator and XPathNodeIterator that are in C#?

Tags: c#, excel, vba, xpathnavigator

I have written a set of VBA macros that search for landmarks in Microsoft Word documents and puts the results into an Excel workbook.  I do other manipulations in Excel.  The source documents are now available in XML. I'd rather not start completely from scratch in C# just yet.

I'm having trouble finding the equivalent of XPathNavigator and XPathNodeIterator in VBA.  I'm loading the input *.xml file as an "MSXML2.DCOMDocument" and it seems to load OK.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/301111/how-to-navigate-xml-with-the-xpathnavigator-class-by-using-visual-basi looks promising. :)